# Upgrading from boostrap 4 to boostrap 5 - Carousel is not working in boostrap5

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

carousel is not working in boostrap5-was upgrading my projects from boostrap 4 to 5, in carousel when i go to last slide and click on next or previous button it doesn't slide,i have to refresh my page again for the slider to load.
Below is the error im getting in console. can anyone please help

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
    at Carousel._setActiveIndicatorElement (carousel.js:359)
    at Carousel._slide (carousel.js:430)
    at Carousel.next (carousel.js:142)
    at Function.carouselInterface (carousel.js:521)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dataApiClickHandler (carousel.js:551)
    at HTMLDocument.handler (event-handler.js:120)
```

Below is the code i have

```
<div class="carousel slide" id="alertsCarousel" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators" id="alertsCarouselIndicators">
        <li data-bs-target="#alertsCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></li>
        @for (var a = 0; a < ViewBag.alertsList.Count; a++)
        {
            <li data-bs-target="#alertsCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="@a+1" class="" aria-label="Slide 2"></li>
        }
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" id="alertsCarouselInnerElements">
        <div class="carousel-item active" id="totalAlertsGlobalItem">
            <div class="card" id="alertsSummaryPanel">
                <div id="alertsSummaryPanelHeading" class="card-header">
                    <h2 class="card-title">
                        <span class="fa fa-tags"></span> Global Alerts Summary
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <div id="alertsSummaryPanelBody" class="card-body">
                    <div id="alertsSummaryContent" class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <div id="tableDiv1" class="table-sm offset-lg-2 col-lg-4">
                                <table class="table" style="font-size: smaller; align-items: center;">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="table-info">
                                                SITES
                                            </th>
                                            <th class="table-info">
                                                TOTAL ALERTS
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody style="font-size: small;">
                                        @for (var i = 0; i < sitesPA.Length / 2; i++)
                                        {
                                            if (sitesPA[i].PresentAlerts != 0)
                                            {
                                                <tr>
                                                    @if (sitesPA[i].PresentAlerts < 20)
                                                    {
                                                        <td class="table-warning">
                                                            @sitesPA[i].SiteName
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="table-warning">
                                                            @sitesPA[i].PresentAlerts
                                                        </td>
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        <td class="table-danger">
                                                            @sitesPA[i].SiteName
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="table-danger">
                                                            @sitesPA[i].PresentAlerts
                                                        </td>
                                                    }
                                                </tr>
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <div id="tableDiv2" class="table-sm col-lg-4">
                                <table class="table" style="font-size: smaller; align-items: center;">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="table-info">
                                                SITES
                                            </th>
                                            <th class="table-info">
                                                TOTAL ALERTS
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody style="font-size: small;">
                                        @for (var j = sitesPA.Length / 2; j < sitesPA.Length; j++)
                                        {
                                            if (sitesPA[j].PresentAlerts != 0)
                                            {
                                                <tr>
                                                    @if (sitesPA[j].PresentAlerts < 20)
                                                    {
                                                        <td class="table-warning">
                                                            @sitesPA[j].SiteName
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="table-warning">
                                                            @sitesPA[j].PresentAlerts
                                                        </td>
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        <td class="table-danger">
                                                            @sitesPA[j].SiteName
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="table-danger">
                                                            @sitesPA[j].PresentAlerts
                                                        </td>
                                                    }
                                                </tr>
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @for (var b = 0; b < ViewBag.alertsList.Count; b++)
        {
            <div class="carousel-item" id="totalAlerts-@alertsListCRT[b][0]-Item">
                <div class="card" id="@alertsListCRT[b][0]-alertsSummaryPanel">
                    <div id="@alertsListCRT[b][0]-alertsSummaryPanelHeading" class="card-header">
                        <h2 class="card-title">
                            <span class="fa fa-tag"></span> @alertsListCRT[b][0] Alerts Summary
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div id="alertsSummaryPanelBody" class="card-body">
                        <div id="alertsSummaryContent" class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <div id="tableDiv1" class="table-sm offset-lg-3 col-lg-6">
                                    <table class="table" style="font-size: small; align-items: center; text-align: center;">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th class="table-info" style="text-align: center;">
                                                    Critical Alerts
                                                </th>
                                                <th class="table-info" style="text-align: center;">
                                                    Warning Alerts
                                                </th>
                                                <th class="table-info" style="text-align: center;">
                                                    Total Alerts
                                                </th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody style="text-align: center; font-size: small;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="table-danger">
                                                    @alertsListCRT[b][2]
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="table-warning">
                                                    @alertsListCRT[b][3]
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="table-active">
                                                    @alertsListCRT[b][4]
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            @if (ViewBag.alertsList[b][2] > 0)
                            {
                                <div class="offset-lg-3 col-lg-6">
                                    <iframe src="@Url.Action("CriticalAlerts", new { id = alertsListCRT[b][1], emailEntryTime = alertsListCRT[b][5] })" scrolling="no" style="width: 100%; height: 300px; border: hidden; background-color: #dfdfdf;"></iframe>
                                </div>
                                <div class="offset-lg-5 col-lg-4" id="presentAlertsButton-@alertsListCRT[b][0]">
                                    <a class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="Click for Report" data-placement="right" href="@Url.Action("PresentAlerts", "ReportDetails", new { id = alertsListCRT[b][1], eet = alertsListCRT[b][5] })">Get Present Alerts Report</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <br />
                                    <br />
                                </div>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <div class="offset-lg-5 col-lg-4" id="presentAlertsButton-@alertsListCRT[b][0]">
                                    <a class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="Click for Report" data-placement="right" href="@Url.Action("PresentAlerts", "ReportDetails", new { id = alertsListCRT[b][1], eet = alertsListCRT[b][5] })">Get Present Alerts Report</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <br />
                                    <br />
                                </div>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#alertsCarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#alertsCarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
</div>
```